# Import database Mysql structure Only

Tags: mysql, import

I have a huge  dump.sql Mysql database of about 3GB that has the structure and the data

Answer (score 1):

3 GB dump isn't huge. You can set up the `MySQL` locally, then import that dumpfile and then dump the base again by `mysqldump` with `--no-data` option.